# When to use squash and rebase?

Tags: git

Trying to learn best practices for git when working in a team.

When is good to use `rebase` and when to use `squash` and when is NOT good  to use them? (scenarios description/examples would be great to illustrate)

Comment: I might be wrong, but this does not seem specifically enough about programming to be on-topic for SO, and I think it's too broad/vague to be of much use to any of the related sites either.

Comment: Best practices are almost always opinion based, which is off topic. This isn't to mention you should be able to find plenty of examples online.

Comment: Can I get some opinions?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250817/git-rebase-loses-history-then-why-rebase?lq=1

Comment: I have written a recomendation for a git workflow in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49922422/457268

Answer (score 1):

When not to use them: If you are afraid of changing the git history, and potentially, losing changes.

When to use: In order to keep a consistent flat history with on-point messages.

- Squash

  - Assume you are working on a branch and do a bunch of commits in the form of `wip templates`, `wip logic`, `wip` -- you then can combine all those intermedient commits into one big commit through squash and create a decent message for them.

I don't squash manually anymore as most decent web clients (e.g. bitbucket, github) allow for squash merging strategy for Pull Requests.

- Rebase

  - Avoids merge commits (tango history)
  - git undoes all your commits, uses a different state of another branch as the new base, and re-applies your commits. Each of your commits will get a new hash in the process.
  - Use it to keep a feature branch up to date with the main branch

Both rebase and squashing change the history and should therfore only be used on feature branches owned by one developer. Your main branch should and any public branch should stay as they are.

(You may allow always for `pull --rebase` instead of `pull` as that only changes the history of your local repository.)